# Angular OnInit HttpClient GET Request Returns Different Data than jQuery AJAX for the Same Endpoint

Tags: javascript, angular, http, flask

I am encountering an issue with Angular's HttpClient where a GET request to my server returns different data compared to a jQuery AJAX request for the same endpoint. I am using Flask for my backend, with CORS: `CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)`. It currently works for POST requests (for sign in and sign out).

**Problem Description:**
When I make a GET request to my Flask server using jQuery AJAX, everything works as expected, and I receive the correct user information. However, when I attempt the same GET request using Angular's HttpClient, I receive a response indicating that the user is not authenticated ({"is_authenticated": False}), even though the user is authenticated.

Here is the working jQuery AJAX code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    fetchPlayerInfo();
});

function fetchPlayerInfo() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/api/player/info",
        xhrFields: {
           withCredentials: true
        },
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("Fetch player info successful:", response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log("Fetch player info failed:", response);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my Angular code that is not working as expected:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrl: './header.component.scss'
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/player/info`;
    this.http.get<any>(url, {withCredentials: true}).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('UserInfo:', data);
    });
  }
}
```

My backend is in Flask. Here is the relevant router endpoint:

```py
@player_bp.route('/info', methods=['GET'])
def get_player_info():
    print("Session: ", dict(session))
    print("Current User: ", current_user)
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        player_info = {"is_authenticated": True, "name": current_user.name}
    else:
        player_info = {"is_authenticated": False}
    return jsonify(player_info)
```

**Additional Observations:**

- The issue only occurs when the Angular HttpClient request is made in the ngOnInit lifecycle hook.
- If I trigger the same HTTP request through an Angular event handler (e.g., by clicking a button), it works correctly, similar to the jQuery AJAX request.
- This behavior leads me to believe that the problem might be related to the timing of the HTTP request or the management of the authentication state during the component's initialization.

**Headers:**

So, here are the headers that I get when doing a GET request after clicking on a button:

```
{'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
 'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Cookie': 'remember_token=176|d927b1c18bf74e8f451c9a350ad85bba5f8ce01422298fcb284e22f1056a030485d9fd203f8f5ff6561cd45a22c7288d99676b76a377c902538f00a3fa746eb4; '
           'session=ve9egd0aRoAgEFLt5QMhsne86EvHwH3eN-1jTgzO-64',
 'Host': 'localhost:5000',
 'Origin': 'http://localhost:4200',
 'Referer': 'http://localhost:4200/',
 'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google '
              'Chrome";v="120"',
 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Linux"',
 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
               'like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
```

And when doing a GET request inside onInit():

```
{'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Content-Length': '0',
 'Host': 'localhost:5000',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux x64) node.js/20.11.0 v8/11.3.244.8-node.17'}
```

Why is Angular's HttpClient not sending the full headers when the request is made in the ngOnInit lifecycle hook?

Comment: The title and the question in the last paragraph are a little misleading ... the HttpClient isn't returning different data, the HttpClient is failing due to an authentication issue

Comment: troubleshooting tip: check the request headers in both cases - what is different?

Comment: Yes, but the reason of the authentication issue is obscure to me. It works when doing a GET request later on (after clicking a button). I'll try to check the headers again.

Comment: I've added the headers information to the question. Can you take a look?

Comment: Oh, so the request is being sent using the server? I didn't expect that. How does the server retain cookies?

Comment: Oh no, the request is being sent via the client (browser). I just got the request from my flask endpoint --- `print(request.headers)`. Anyway, I think I've found the issue. I was adding the `provideClientHydration` to my providers list. After removing it, everything works! I just don't know why. Does it block GET requests until the DOM is fully loaded?

Comment: why does the user-agent include `node.js/20.11.0` then?

Comment: Well, honestly, I don't know. That confused me too, as my server/backend is running in Python/Flask.